# How to apply some logic to dataframe column faster and with elegant coding

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, iterator

I'm reading a csv file with many columns and one of them is TOD (time of the day). Some events go past midnight and instead of rolling back to 00:00 the time just keeps increasing past 24:00. For example 23:59:50, 24:00:01, 24:00:10,...)
The EntryTOD gets parsed as string.

I want to apply a simple logic that is the time is greater than 24, just subtract 24 hours. This is the code I have:

```
for row in f2.itertuples():
    # Fix times > 24h
    if int(row.EntryTOD[0:2]) >= 24:
        actualTime =  int(row.EntryTOD[0:2]) - 24
        f2.EntryTOD[row.Index-1] = str(actualTime) + row.EntryTOD[2:]
```

This code works but is a little slow for 80k+ rows. Takes about 30-40 seconds to run.

My questions are:

1) is there a faster way to do this?

2) also, since I'm not great with Python, is there a more elegant way? It might still involve iterating through the entire column, but I have the feeling that this could be done in 1 line of code

Thank you in advance,

Guido

SOLUTION:
thanks to Rene:

```
f2.EntryTOD = f2.EntryTOD.apply(lambda x: str(int(x.split(':')[0])-24)+x[2:] if int(x.split(':')[0]) > 23 else x)
```

This is very fast and a single liner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
f2 = pd.DataFrame(['23:59', '23:59:59', '24:00', '24:01', '25:25:25'], columns=['TOD'])
f2.TOD.apply(lambda x: f"{int(x.split(':')[0])-24}:{x.split(':')[1]}" if int(x.split(':')[0]) > 23 else x)
```

Result:

```
0       23:59
1    23:59:59
2        0:00
3        0:01
4        1:25
Name: TOD, dtype: object
```

Comment: awesome, I think we are close. For some reasons it's not working.
Also wouldn't this be more compact:
f2.EntryTOD.apply(lambda x: str(int(x.split(':')[0])-24)+x[2:] if int(x.split(':')[0]) > 23 else x)

Comment: I tested the logic with some print and it works. The f2.EntryTOD just doesn't get updated...

Comment: This works: f2.EntryTOD = f2.EntryTOD.apply(lambda x: str(int(x.split(':')[0])-24)+x[2:] if int(x.split(':')[0]) > 23 else x)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
# Sample df
data = [
    ['25:22:22', 1, 5],
    ['01:01:01', 36, 2]
]
cols = ['EntryTOD', 'two', 'three']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
```

`df`

```
    EntryTOD    two three
0   25:22:22    1   5
1   01:01:01    36  2
```

Solution:

```
df['hour'] = (df['EntryTOD'].str[0:2]).astype(int)

df.loc[
    df.hour >= 24, 'hour'
] = df.loc[df.hour >= 24, 'hour'] - 24

# Edit EntryTOD variable
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.EntryTOD.iloc[i] = df.EntryTOD.iloc[i].replace(
        df['EntryTOD'].str[0:2].iloc[i], '0'+df['hour'].astype(str).iloc[i]
    )
```

Output:

```
    EntryTOD    two three   hour
0   01:22:22    1    5      1
1   01:01:01    36   2      1
```